# Swift - Present a UIView (not a ViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition

I have two `UIViewControllers` and I would like to `.present` the gray `UIView` like you would usually present a `ViewController` (appearing bottom up and user can slide down to dismiss).

Screenshots for a better understanding:

[image]
[image]

The bottomBar is a `ContainerView` and should not change by switching between the VC's, only the gray `UIView` which you can see in the 2nd picture.

I know I could just `.present` `ViewControllerB` without an animation and then just let the `UIView` appear from out of the screen. But if I do it like this the user is not able to drag down the `UIView` to `dismiss` it.

This is how I present `ViewControllerB` ("wishlistViewController) at the moment.

```
let wishlistViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WishlistVC") as! WishlistViewController

        wishlistViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext

        self.navigationController?.present(wishlistViewController, animated: false)
}
```

**Main Problem** is that my `UIView` is not fullscreen. Otherwise I could just `.present` `ViewControllerB`. However, with my design the background image would be animated by `.presenting` or `.dismissing` as well and I do not want that.

There is probably a very easy solution for this but I couldn't find on presenting ONLY a `UIView`.
Grateful for any tips :)

Comment: You should use a custom tabbar view instead of container view for the + button. Then you can have multiple view controllers as it seems like ;)

Comment: sorry I am not following you there. What do you mean by "can have multiple view controllers" ?

Comment: One view controller for each of the items. So touching any of them will present the corresponding view controller *while* bottom bar view is keeping seamlessly.

Comment: sorry I was unclear in my question. `ViewControllerB` appears after the user clicks on a `cell` not the bottomBar. BottomBar is unrelated to this problem I think

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: No you described it right. Imagine the twitter app. almost anything you touch will open a new page without changing the tweet button. And note that controllers can be drag to dismissible. Even this is a normal behavior since iOS 13.

Comment: I would like to have the `.present` and `.dismiss` functions to apply to my gray `UIView` in `ViewControllerB`

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini but my UIView is not fullScreen. My background image should not be animated either. Only the `UIView`. Sorry a bit new to this. I hope you get what I mean

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I just updated my question. Look at **Main Problem** . I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are two answers I can think of:

1) If you want, you could just animate it in from the bottom using UIView.animate() on a y-position constraint it has, or on its layer's y-position attribute. You could then attach a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to it so that if you swipe down on it, it will animate back down.

2) Make your views that you'd like to present viewControllers and have them be presented with a custom modal animation. This sounds like more work than you wanna do though. Here's a cool tutorial on youtube that walks you through how to create a custom animation transition between 2 view controllers:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9sH_VxPPo4

However, as far as I know, those .dismiss and .present methods are **only** meant for view controllers. Hopefully one of the two options I gave were helpful!

Comment: thanks for your answer! I wasn't aware of the UISwipeGestureRecognizer. I will give that a try.

Comment: I tried implementing the `SwipeGesture` but getting the same animation as with the normal `dismiss` function seems pretty complicated tbh. Any idea on how I could solve my problem with a custom modal animation? Even if that will take a maybe a bit more work.

Comment: never mind. I actually got it working with `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` . Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear :)